# Plotly dropdown for multiple pie charts w/subsets

Tags: python, plotly, subset, dropdown, pie-chart

I'm new to python (programming in general). I have 7 identical dfs (save the values), for each of which I have plotted a pie chart of the index (department) with 4 subsets (1 for each column). Each df is representative of a Customer Profile's total spend per dept. and region.

I want to create one figure in Jupyter notebook with a dropdown that allows me to show each pie chart one at a time (obviously).

mamp_subset: there are actually 21 rows but shortened for convenience...

|  | Midwest | Northeast | South | West |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| produce | 4050720.6 | 3031984.8 | 5611374.9 | 4306556.0 |
| dairy eggs | 2408227.1 | 1813007.6 | 3294240.6 | 2595948.5 |
| beverages | 1097276.9 | 862985.1 | 1532102.1 | 1192854.9 |
| frozen | 932023.9 | 680308.6 | 1263805.1 | 991491.6 |
| pantry | 813371.3 | 597606.7 | 1100308.0 | 865809.8 |

My code:

```
myexplode = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1]
mywedge_props = {'linewidth' : 1, 'edgecolor' : 'black'}

# Create a figure and a set of subplots
fig1, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 12))

def my_autopct(pct):
    return ('%1.2f%%' % pct) if pct > 5.5 else ''

# Plot each column of the dataframe as a pie chart
for i, column in enumerate(mamp_subset.columns):
    wedges, texts, autotexts = axes[i // 2, i % 2].pie(mamp_subset[column].sort_values(), 
                                           labels=mamp_subset.sort_values(by=[column], ascending=True).index, 
                                           autopct='%1.2f%%', 
                                           wedgeprops=mywedge_props, 
                                           explode=myexplode,  
                                           startangle=90)
    threshold = 6
    for label, pct_label in zip(texts, autotexts):
        pct_value = pct_label.get_text().rstrip('%')
        if float(pct_value) < threshold:
            label.set_text('')
            pct_label.set_text('')
            
    axes[i // 2, i % 2].set_title(column, fontsize='12', fontweight='bold')

# get current handles and labels
# this must be done AFTER plotting
current_handles, current_labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()

# sort or reorder the labels and handles
reversed_handles = list(reversed(current_handles))
reversed_labels = list(reversed(current_labels))

# call plt.legend() with the new values
plt.legend(reversed_handles,reversed_labels, title='Departments', bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 1.8)) 

fig1.suptitle('Middle Aged Married Parent', fontsize='20', fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

Result:
[mamp_subset pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmhY2.png)

I've checked multiple threads dealing with similar issues and have tried using callbacks, interact, traces with updatemenu but I don't know how to implement the code I've written already.

I also have all 7 dfs combined as 1 larger df. Is it better to work with one df or multiple? I'm at a loss.

Any help with this would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary of pie charts created for each column of the data frame in a dictionary format. Determine the region for initial display and create the initial graph. Next, add graphs using the graph data in the dictionary.
After adding, detach the first pie. Finally, create a button menu. This creation method is customized for your data from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68770320/piechart-dropdown-in-plotly-python). I have moved the position a bit on the drop down. Also, plotly.express has a feature for creating subplots, so you can easily create subplots.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import plotly.express as px

data = '''
    Midwest Northeast   South   West
produce 4050720.6   3031984.8   5611374.9   4306556.0
"dairy eggs"    2408227.1   1813007.6   3294240.6   2595948.5
beverages   1097276.9   862985.1    1532102.1   1192854.9
frozen  932023.9    680308.6    1263805.1   991491.6
pantry  813371.3    597606.7    1100308.0   865809.8
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

figs = {col_name: px.pie(df[col_name], values=df[col_name], names=df.index) for col_name in df.columns}

first_region = df.columns[1]
fig = figs[first_region].update_traces(visible=True, pull=[0.1,0,0,0,0])
for k in figs.keys():
    if k != first_region:
        fig.add_traces(figs[k].data)
        fig.update_traces(pull=[0.1,0,0,0,0])
        
fig.update_layout(
    title='Middle Aged Marred Parent',
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": k,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [{"visible": [kk == k for kk in figs.keys()]}],
                }
                for k in figs.keys()
            ],
        "active": 0,
        "x": 0.0,
        "xanchor": "left",
        "y": 1.05,
        "yanchor": "top"
        }
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

**plotly.express: facet graph**

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_long = df.melt(id_vars='index', value_vars=df.columns[1:], var_name='region')
df_long.head()
    index   region  value
0   produce Midwest 4050720.6
1   dairy eggs  Midwest 2408227.1
2   beverages   Midwest 1097276.9
3   frozen  Midwest 932023.9
4   pantry  Midwest 813371.3

fig = px.pie(df_long,
             values='value',
             names='index',
             facet_col='region',
             facet_col_wrap=2,
             facet_row_spacing=0.1,
             facet_col_spacing=0.1,
             title='Middle Aged Marred Parent',
             hover_data=['value'],
            )
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textinfo='percent+label', pull=[0.1,0,0,0,0])
fig.update_layout(width=800, height=800)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this does help but I think I was a little unclear in my OP. I need the dropdown menu to be the 7 different profiles, not the regions. I was able to use widgets to show what I want, but I can't change the dropdown names <https://drive.google.com/file/d/13yDw2UU-TjWLK4FxgUrKZqkIxRlSZZ70/view?usp=sharing>.

Comment: I am confused. The question doesn't talk about widgets, and I'm not sure how many dropdowns I need and what functions to assign to each. Let's update the question first. The dropdowns in my code use the column name as the name of the dictionary for each graph, so you can change the contents of the dropdowns by editing them. Is the visualization library you want to use plotly?